# Unable to connect to a share folder trough VPN when connecting from within a network

Tags: vpn, sharing

on our main office network I defined a VPN within a TP-Link router to allow connection from outside office to two local servers (Windows Server 2008) where there are few shared folders and a web application.
When at home, with my laptop (Windows 10) connected to the Internet (hotspot with my telephone) I can connect to the office via VPN and access both the web application and the shared folders.
Problems start when I want to access the shared folders via VPN from another office site using a computer in a local network. VPN starts normally and I can even access the web application, but there is no way to access the shared folders. Here is what I have tried:

1. Enabled SMB1, client and server, on Windows Features;
2. Changed the workgroup name on the remote computer to be the same as the workgroup in the main office network (this solved the problem on my home laptop);
3. Verified that the Workstation service is running on the remote computer;
4. Verified that Network discovery and file and print sharing is enabled on remote computer;

I suppose that there is nothing more to do on the router or on the server, once everything work fine with my home laptop using the VPN.

From the remote computer in the second office I can ping the two servers when connected with the VPN and I get an IP address from the router DHCP, which allows me to open a web browser with a local address (in the main office) where we have a web application.

I am stuck at this point and cannot find a similar problem description (and possible solution) on posts on the Internet.

Any help greatly appreciated.

ipconfig from home laptop (where everything work fine)
PPP Adapter VPN:
IPv4 Address  10.105.40.201
Subnet mask  255.255.255.255
Default gateway  0.0.0.0

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:
IPv4 Address 192.168.43.100
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway  192.168.43.1

ipconfig from second office's computer (where I cannot connect to the share folders on the main office)
PPP Adapter VPN:
IPv4 Address 10.105.40.200
Subnet mask  255.255.255.255
Default gateway  0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter:
IPv4 address  192.168.0.30
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.0.1

Comment: **SMB1 _should not_ be enabled** for any purpose, as there's no reason to utilize it, and more importantly, it's been actively exploited for the past 2 - 3years, being one of the main vectors for ransomware.  SMB1 is archaic, with every device supporting at least SMB2, and enabling it is asking to be exploited, especially as a business.

Comment: Please verify if home laptop's subnet mask and second office's PC is accurate, as it should not be the broadcast subnet mask [`255.255.255.255`].  If that is what the subnet mask is set to, it's not a valid subnet mask... please see [Subnet Mask Cheat Sheet](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html) for valid subnet masks... also, why don't those two have a DNS or Gateway IPs set?

Comment: If I disable SMB1, even my home laptop cannot access anymore the sharing folders. I need it because of Windows Server 2008 on the remote server.

Comment: I cannot technically answer your questions. As I said, that are the addresses that I get when typing ipconfig on both home laptop (working fine) and second office's computer (not accessing the share folders).

Answer (score 0):

*Problems start when I want to access the shared folders via VPN from another office site using a computer in a local network.*

You know the VPN is working properly when off the main network. So the setup is likely good.

The company network is very likely on the same subnet as the VPN and that prevents connecting to folders.  You need a different subnet in this office environment.

Comment: ipconfig from home laptop (where everything work fine)
PPP Adapter VPN:
IPv4 Address  10.105.40.201
Subnet mask  255.255.255.255
Default gateway  0.0.0.0

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:
IPv4 Address 192.168.43.100
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway  192.168.43.1

ipconfig from second office's computer (where I cannot connect to the share folders on the main office)
PPP Adapter VPN:
IPv4 Address 10.105.40.200
Subnet mask  255.255.255.255
Default gateway  0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter:
IPv4 address  192.168.0.30
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.0.1